# How to do 2 sql command

Tags: php, mysql

the first sql command is:

```
INSERT INTO table1(post) values('$post');
```

and after insert $post I want to update a column in another table
so I used:

```
UPDATE table2 SET score='$score' where name='$name';
```

how do I combine these 2 command or do them at the same time ?

I am new to mysql :) 

here is what I want:
a user go to my website and post an string after post it the score of that user will be update

Comment: use procedure for multiple sql statement in one go.

Comment: Typically, you would wrap them in a transaction, thus guaranteeing that either they would both take effect, or neither would take effect, guaranteeing the consistency of your data.

Answer (score 3):

If for every `insert` you `update`, you could add triggers to your database.

Code :

```
delimiter |

CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TriggerName
AFTER INSERT
ON table1
BEGIN
     UPDATE table2 SET score=score + 1 WHERE name=INSERTED.user_id
    # INSERTED is the row added to table1
END;

delimiter ;
```

If you have the user id field in `table1`, this should work.

Otherwise, if you use a relation-table, like `user_post` (id, user_id, post_id), you have to [declare](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/declare_vars.php) a variable to store the id temporarily

Comment: Please I'm new to mysql can you give an example for my code?

Comment: Note that by using triggers, you are splitting your application in two parts: One is issuing the SQL, and the new part is now in the database. Have a plan how to update and maintain this new part of the application.

Comment: This trigger has one drawback: It increases the score by one. The original question sets the score to a defined value from outside, without explaining how the value was calculated. Why do you increase the score? It may as well be that you have an amount of score to use for posting, and it should be decreased now. Or the score is some arbitrary value unrelated to previous scores.

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed it.. You are right. That point makes Triggers is not appropriate in this case.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work .The score will increase by 1 :))

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like maintaining two applications from now on (the one you have and the one you create in the database by adding triggers or functions), there is a simpler solution:

Use only one piece of PHP code to add this stuff to the database (like a function or class' method), and simply send the two queries one after the other.

For extra data consistency, you should use a transaction, which is simply two more queries, or an appropriate usage of the database classes. For example, MySQLi has http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php to start the transaction and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php to end it (or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php to undo).

```
function writePostWithScore($post, $name, $score) {
    // have the mysqli connection object somewhere
    $mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table1 (post) values('".$mysqli->real_escape_string($post)."')");
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE table2 SET score='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($score)."' where name='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($name)."'");
    $mysqli->commit();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I always create functions.  Create 2 functions.  One that insert, the otherone will update.  Call what you need.

Comment: Thanks but I think we should use trggers

Comment: Ohhh okeyy that is new for me.  I will google :) thanks